# Website admin panel with iPad support

Tags: ipad, cross-browser, scroll

We're building an admin panel for managing bookings and payments. I would like to use the style of Apple Mail on the iPad as it is clean, simple and user friendly. We are quite capable of building it but the question remains on scrolling content.

Image a Clients page. We'd want a list of clients on the left and onclick the content to load on the right. On iPad mail these two colums scroll independently. Yet to achieve this on our own pages I have found only a handful of inadequate solutions.

> 1.) Overflow content and two finger scroll
>
> ```
> - no scrollbars
> - not particularly user friendly
> ```
>
> 2.) JS libraries such as iScroll
>
> ```
> - over complex and  lacing in cross browser compatibility.
> ```

Thus any other simple ideas on how to do this. Would a good old fashioned frameset accomplish this goal?

Comment: There's a (non-free) Wordpress plugin that manages to do what you want (WPtouch Pro) but I haven't yet worked out how they do it!

Comment: @hood We have now built it, but thank you for your help

Answer (score -1):

What's wrong with two divs with `overflow: auto;`?

Comment: As I said in the question. Horrible in practical 2 finger scroll and no scroll bars

Comment: If you add overflow auto and your div content is longer then your div itself, it will generate scrollbars. What do you mean with '2 finger scroll'.

Comment: We are referring to the IPAD scrolling issue as outlined in the question. iPad will not add scrollbars. IPad will do nothing but allow you to scroll with two fingures with no obvious signs of scrollability